# Reading what's available from Socket without blocking

Tags: java

I am working on a server which reads data sent by the client, but the size is not known neither can I change the client to send the size.

I want to read the data from client till it blocks and waits for server's response. I tried using `available()`, it works sometimes but sometimes it just returns zero even when there's some data in stream.

```
while((len = in.available()) != 0)
    in.read(b,0,len);
```

Is there any way to do this in Java? I'm aware of asynchronous methods, but have never tried that, so if someone can provide a short example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `available()` is the only way to do it without resorting to asynchronous methods.

You don't really need to rely on the value returned by `available()`; just check that there is "some" data available to make sure that `read` will not block. You must, however, check the value returned by `read` (the actual number of bytes read into the array):

```
// Process all data currently available
while (in.available() != 0)
{
    int nb = in.read(b);
    // Process nb bytes
}
```

Note that `available` returning 0 does not mean that the end of the data was reached -- it merely means that there is no data available for immediate consumption (data may become available in the next millisecond). Thus you'll need to have some other mechanism in order for the server to know that the client will not send any more data and is waiting for a response instead.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but what specifically is that *other* mechanism?

Comment: That is application specific. Depending on the application, you may want to prefix every chunk of data with a length byte, or define an "end of data" marker, or rely on timeouts, etc.

Comment: Got it. I'm sending json messages over sockets, and allowing a CLI where users can enter their own message, so prefixing length might not be a great idea. What is usually considered a good "end of data" marker? I'm using a silly [END] right now and that just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664867/end-of-message-string-for-sockets). Looks like what I need!

Answer (score 4):

[`InputStream` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) for the method  `available()` clearly states that

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer
>   intended to hold all data in this stream.

You should instead try the [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)) method to read data into a fixed size buffer allocated with, say 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of solutions but the only one I found which wasn't blocking execution was:

```
BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yourInputStream));
String line;
while(inStream.ready() && (line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```